# Botão FAB + NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

Suponho que seja um problema simples, mas não consigo visualizar a solução. Criei um botão flutuante (FAB) em um Fragment no Android, e ao tentar configurar o ClickListener, recebo um erro de NullPointer. Seguem os códigos:

## xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right|end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"/>
```

## MainActivity.java

```
FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         Intent criar = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Fragment1.class);
         startActivity(criar);
     }
}
```

A mensagem de erro diz que o código tenta chamar o método `setOnClickListener` em um objeto nulo.

Qualquer dica é bem vinda. Agradeço.

Comment: Você recebe `NullPointerException`, pois o `floatingActionButton` está null. O XML que ele está declarado é referente ao seu `MainActivity`?

Comment: Sim. Mas por quê está null? O findViewById não deveria ser a atribuição necessária?

Answer (score 0):

Verifiquei agora na sua pergunta que você declarou o `FloatingActionButton` no seu Fragment. Dessa forma você não pode utilizar o findViewById() direto da sua `MainActivity`, e esse é o motivo de ele estar recebendo null.

Veja bem a [documentação](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById(int)):

> Finds a view that was identified by the id attribute from the XML that was processed in onCreate(Bundle).

Ou seja, utilizando o `findViewById()` direto da sua `MainActivity`, a função procurará este `FloatingActionButton` dentro do `layout` que está ligado a sua `MainActivity` e não do seu `Fragment`.

Para resolver o problema basta você instanciar esse `FloatingActionButton` dentro do seu `Fragment` e definir seu evento de click lá dentro, ou você mover esse `FloatingActionButton` para o layout da sua `MainActivity`.

Comment: Valeu pela dica, Vitor!